# mongoose - perfroming CRUD operations on a sub document

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating a mern app, and pretty new to mongodb and mongoose, and I'm currently struggling with the concept of the subdocument in mongodb and how to perform crud operations in express. I've been researching and haven't found many tutorials or articles on subdocuments, mostly the referenced documents and population.

I have two separate schemas

```
var ProjectSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    description:String,
    lists: [ListSchema]
})

var ListSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
     name: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
})
```

Currently, i'm trying to insert data into the List schema.

```
listRouter.post('/api/project/:projectId/list/new', asyncMiddleware(async function(req,res,next){
        Project.findById(req.params.projectId, await function(err,items){
            items.lists.push(req.body)
            items.save();
            res.json(items)
        })
}))
```

What happens is that the data are inserted into the Project.lists but when I check the List collection in mongodb, it's empty.

From my reading the sub documents documentation , it stats you can't save the sub documents individually, you have to do via the parent document- which I have in the code above. 
Doesn't the List collection supposed to automatically get the new data after saving the Project document? Or something else is happening? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: can you also add what you are sending inside `req.body`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The req.body contains the value of posted lists. There is no issue there. It turns out that I didn't quite grasped the nested models concept. as Ive been researching that nested models aren't saved individually and if you want them to be that way, you'd have to use the reference model.